# Send workflow emails to the managers of multiple users added to "person or group" column/field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a simple SharePoint list and I want to send multiple emails when a new item is added:

1. Email to the creator (straight-forward)
2. Emails to each of the potentially multiple users added to "person or group" column/field (straight-forward)
3. Emails to the **managers** of the potentially multiple users added to "person or group" column/field (is this possible)

Does anybody know how I can achieve automating emails to the managers? Is this something that can be achieved using a 2010 or 2013 workflow in SharePoint Designer? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Does your "person or group" allow groups as well, or only users? Do you aim for a solution where you can lookup the manager of users in the groups added to the "person or group" field?

Comment: Just users. So I just need to get the email addresses for the managers of the users added to this column (1 or more)

Answer (score 0):

i am assigning variable

Set Variable: v to [%Current Item:Created By%]
Call https://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.... HTTP web service with Variable: a (ResponseContent to Variable: b |ResponseHeaders to responseHeaders |ResponseStatusCode to Variable: responseCode )

Will This help?

Answer (score -1):

To get the Manager details using SharePoint designer workflow 2013 you will need to use the HTTP Web Service call with REST endpoint URI. Listed below the useful endpoint URI for getting Manager details.

After getting the manager account name in above step, use that to find the email id by again calling a HTTP Service using the below endpoint URL and get the required property from that.

**Get all properties of Specific User:**

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=’i:0%23.f|membership|mbepari@aataaq.onmicrosoft.com’
```

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v=’contoso\mbepari’
```

**Get Specific UserProfile Property of Specific User:**

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName=’LastName’)?@v=’i:0%23.f|membership|mbepari@aataaq.onmicrosoft.com’
```

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName=’LastName’)?@v=’contoso\mbepari’
```

Reference: http://spmavericks.com/2014/10/30/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-find-manager-alternative/

Comment: I was aware of the HTTP Web Service call - but I'm not sure how that helps with this scenario. I can use this call to get the manager details of the creator. But my question is how can I get the manager details of each of the users added to the "person or group" column.

Comment: If you were able to get the list of all users from the people picker field, you may get their managers from it

Comment: "If you were able to get the list of all users from the people picker field" - I have this list already  - "you may get their managers from it" - How?